# How to delete/hide the closest element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to delete/hide the closest element using jquery?
I want hide the closest element with the class 'tiny-user-block' when I click on deny.

**Jquery:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.deny-friend-request', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var obj = $(this);
  var friendship_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-friendship-id'));
  var from_user_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-profile-id'));
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').css('background', '#82b964');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Friend');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').addClass('no-friend-sent');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').removeClass('is-pending-friend-request');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul').addClass('hidden');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .accept-friend-request').addClass('cancel-friend-request');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .cancel-friend-request').html('<a href="#">Cancel</a>');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .cancel-friend-request').removeClass('accept-friend-request');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .deny-friend-request').remove();
  obj.closest('.friend-request').attr('title', 'Add as friend').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
  obj.closest('.tiny-user-block').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/pxcwveuh/

**EDIT:**
I found the problem.
It seems that's happens if you're using the "slim" version of jQuery. Only the "full" version of jQuery includes animation effects.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the same `data-friendship-id` attribute to it and then search for it. That's the most efficient way. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sbgax5h9/

.fadeOut() is not a function for some reason. Probably something with jQuery version. So I replaced it by .hide().

UPD: It has something to do with caching tidyBlock first. Please see updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/sbgax5h9/1/ . Works without Ids now.

Comment: hmmm...I don't want to use data-friendship-id attr in class, the best way for me is to use closest because I have multiple users to display.

Comment: thanks for your reply....In my site all events use fadeOut, it will weird if only one doesn't use it

Comment: Hide is too ugly that's why I prefer use a function with an effect to hide/delete an element.

Comment: You can use fadeOut it’s just seems to not supported by the fiddle version of jQuery. It’s saying fadeOut is not a function in console .

Answer (score 0):

> I want hide the closest element with the class 'tiny-user-block' when I click on deny.

That's straightforward, since the deny button is contained inside `tiny-user-block` all you need is `closest()`:

```js
$('body').on('click','.deny-friend-request', function() {
  $(this).closest('.tiny-user-block').hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="tiny-user-block clearfix">
    <div class="user-img"> <img src="http://img.actucine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Captain-America.jpg" alt="User" width="50" height="50" /> </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Mark</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Ranking: <strong>1</strong></li>
      <li>Friends: <strong>42</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="btn-group" style="text-transform: lowercase;margin-left:15px">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs friend-request tooltiped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Friend request in pending...">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger add-friend-single-btn is-pending-friend-request dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="min-width:65px;" data-profile-id="1">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Pending
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="accept-friend-request" data-friendship-id="320" data-profile-id="1"><a href="#">Accept</a></li>
            <li class="deny-friend-request" data-friendship-id="320" data-profile-id="1"><a href="#">
                                deny</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just as a side note, you're really doing a lot of extra unnecessary work (both for yourself, and the user's processor) when you do stuff like this:

```
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').css('background', '#82b964');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Friend');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').addClass('no-friend-sent');
  obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').removeClass('is-pending-friend-request');
```

Every time you call 'closest' and 'find' the browser has to crawl through the DOM again to find the same nodes you were just accessing in the previous line.

You can speed things up quite a bit, and save yourself a lot of typing, and make your code a lot more readable, by either chaining those together:

```
obj.closest('.friend-request')
    .find('.is-pending-friend-request')
    .css('background', '#82b964')
    .addClass('no-friend-sent')
    .removeClass('is-pending-friend-request')
    .html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Friend')
```

...or cacheing the DOM search in a temporary variable:

```
var isPendingRequest = obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request');
isPendingRequest.addClass(...) // etc
```